# Dataframe join two table with existing data

Tags: python, dataframe

Want to **based** on `dataframe(e)` to **join** `dataframe(f)` with same `column"B"` which is only `column"B"` records, `2,3,5,6,13,14` have `*` records at `column"C"` final result have **only three columns** `column"A"` `column"B"` `column"C"`

**Python code**

```
e = [[1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0], [3.0, 4.0], [4.0, 5.0], [5.0, 6.0], [6.0, 7.0], [7.0, 8.0], [8.0, 9.0], [9.0, 10.0], [10.0, 11.0], [11.0, 12.0], [12.0, 13.0], [13.0, 14.0]]
f = [['2', '*'], ['3', '*'], ['5', '*'], ['6', '*'], ['13', '*'], ['14', '*']]
e = pd.DataFrame(e)
e.columns = ['A', 'B']
f = pd.DataFrame(f)
f.columns = ['B', 'C']
pd.concat([e,f], axis = 1, join="outer")
```

**Execution Result**

```
    A   B   B   C
0   1.0 2.0 2   *
1   2.0 3.0 3   *
2   3.0 4.0 5   *
3   4.0 5.0 6   *
4   5.0 6.0 13  *
5   6.0 7.0 14  *
6   7.0 8.0 NaN NaN
7   8.0 9.0 NaN NaN
8   9.0 10.0    NaN NaN
9   10.0    11.0    NaN NaN
10  11.0    12.0    NaN NaN
11  12.0    13.0    NaN NaN
12  13.0    14.0    NaN NaN
```

**Expected Result**

```
    A   B   C
0   1.0 2.0 NaN
1   2.0 3.0 NaN
2   3.0 4.0 *
3   4.0 5.0 *
4   5.0 6.0 NaN
5   6.0 7.0 *
6   7.0 8.0 *
7   8.0 9.0 NaN
8   9.0 10.0 NaN
9   10.0    11.0 NaN
10  11.0    12.0    NaN
11  12.0    13.0    *
12  13.0    14.0    *
```

Comment: Why column `C` at index `0` is `NaN`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.merge()` to merge the dataframes on column `B`. First we have to set the dtype of `f['B']` to `float` to allow merging on that column and given your desired outcome:

```
f['B'] = f['B'].astype(float)
```

Then we can merge on `B`:

```
e.merge(f, how='outer', on='B')
```

Output:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | * |
| 1 | 2.0 | 3.0 | * |
| 2 | 3.0 | 4.0 | nan |
| 3 | 4.0 | 5.0 | * |
| 4 | 5.0 | 6.0 | * |
| 5 | 6.0 | 7.0 | nan |
| 6 | 7.0 | 8.0 | nan |
| 7 | 8.0 | 9.0 | nan |
| 8 | 9.0 | 10.0 | nan |
| 9 | 10.0 | 11.0 | nan |
| 10 | 11.0 | 12.0 | nan |
| 11 | 12.0 | 13.0 | * |
| 12 | 13.0 | 14.0 | * |